# Add tid or name as a class to each item of a taxonomy term

Tags: entities, theming, taxonomy-terms

I'd like to add the term ID or the name of the term as a class to each one of my taxonomy terms on a node page.

note that I'm not using views, so I wonder how can I achieve this via template.php or any customized tpl.php, I couldn't find any module as well to add class to each term separately.

thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can modify the output of any field with:

- [drupal standard field tlps](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21theme%21field.tpl.php/7)

Possible override templates are:

- field.tpl.php
- field--content-type.tpl.php
- field--field-name--content-type.tpl.php
- field--field-type.tpl.php
- field--field-name.tpl.php

  So according to your specification in comment
  `"product_display"  and the reference term field is "field_product_specs"`
  your custom `tpl` file name should be **field--field-product-specs--product-display.tpl.php**

OR

- [Fences](https://www.drupal.org/project/fences)

> Fences is a an easy-to-use tool to specify an HTML element for each
> field. This element choice will propagate everywhere the field is
> used, such as teasers, RSS feeds and Views. You don't have to keep
> re-configuring the same HTML element over and over again every time
> you display the field.

Comment: Thanks Jorgetutor for the answer, but can you help me out with the content of the field--field-name--content-type.tpl.php ? considering the content-type is "product_display" and the reference term field is "field_product_specs" ?

Comment: Also Fences is an amazing module but it's not working with setting a class per item for fields with multiple values such as taxonomy terms