# How to add a taxonomy term value as a class?

Tags: theming, 8, nodes, users, taxonomy-terms

I am trying to target a specific div with CSS. But for that, I need a unique class in order to target a specific taxonomy term. I look at [this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/140751/add-tid-or-name-as-a-class-to-each-item-of-a-taxonomy-term), but that doesn't work as it will target all taxonomy terms.

I have created a `vocabulary` called 'Titles' which has the following terms in it:

> [image]

Which will display the following in my browser:

> [image]

Note that I am not using a view to display these titles. Instead, I used a preprocess function:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  $variables['authortitle'] = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getViewBuilder('user')->view($variables['node']->getOwner(), 'nodetitle');
}
```

#### How can I add "Writer" as a class to the `<a>` tag?

Answer (score 2):

To append a term's name as CSS class to the term field itself you could simply implement [`template_preprocess_field()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_field/8.2.x) like so:

```
use Drupal\taxonomy\Entity\Term;
use Drupal\Component\Utility\Html;

/**
 * Implements template_preprocess_field().
 */
function MYTHEME_preprocess_field(&$variables) {

  if ($variables['field_name'] == 'field_MYFIELD') {

    if (!$variables['element']['#items']->isEmpty()) {

      // Get the term ID.
      $tid = $variables['element']['#items']->getValue()[0]['target_id'];

      // Load the term.
      $term = Term::load($tid);

      // Get the term name.
      $name = $term->getName();

      // Make the term name safe to be used as CSS class.
      $name_safe = strtolower(Html::cleanCssIdentifier($name));

      // Append class.
      $variables['attributes']['class'][] = $name_safe;
    };
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using content values for classes can be accomplished in twig. For something as simple as your example above I'd override taxonomy-term.html.twig for my theme. 
Adding `class="{{ name}}"` to the 'a' tag in there should do it.

You could also use `attributes.addClass()` similar to the way node information is added in those twig files.

Comment: Hi @lynbermt, thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, this only works on a taxonomy page. I am loading a taxonomy term on the homepage using field.html.twig. Your solutions doesn't work here, do you have another suggestion? :)

Comment: You could add a custom variable via `template_preprocess_field()`. What's in your field twig file now?

Comment: I managed to add the value as a class with `class="{{ item.content }}"`. This only works on taxonomy page as I put it in the field.twig.html.

Answer (score 0):

I find very useful to have taxonomy based classes in the `<body>` tag.

Typical: you want to hide the "share to social" field form some kind (term) of pages.

Having a term based class in body you can

```
body.tid-123 field-with-social-links  {
  display none;
}
```

Find out how to in https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/220751/13760